# Change application signature?

Tags: c++, exe, digital-signature

Suppose I want to give someone my application. Now I want to give it to someone else but with a different application signature. What can I change in my code that changes the application signature? Can It be a variable name? What can it be?

Comment: what is an *application signature*?

Comment: Details are probably implementation and operating system specific.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that causes a binary change is OK. A single string change, such as "build 4321" -> " build 4322"  is already sufficient.

Variable names are almost always stripped from executables. (There are some debug settings which may affect this, but you shouldn't release debug binaries)

Comment: So, in a nutshell you can modify any varible name or string value to change the binary?

Comment: @michealbell: No, variable names which are stripped (removed) from the binary do not affect the binary. How could they? They're no longer in.

Comment: Oh, sorry I misread. So you said I simple string change will affect binary, yeah?

Comment: Indeed. Go ahead, try it.

Comment: Thank you. How can I tell that the signature is actually changed though?

Comment: Also, if I had a function that would change the value of a string inside the program, on each run would that change the binary?

Comment: @michealbell Changing a string at run-time won't change the binary.